# Make VoiceOver read the 'title' attribute of an empty <div>

Tags: html, title, voiceover

I have a `div` with background image which is clickable. The `div` doesn't have any content and I have provided a `title` to that.

How can I enable the iPad VoiceOver feature to read the `title` for that `div`?

If not `title`, can we use any ARIA attribute to make VoiceOver read that attribute?

Comment: "I have a div with background image which is clickable. The doesn't have any content " — Don't do that. Use an `<img>` with an `alt` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

you can add some dummy text to that div and set

```
font-size:0px
```

in your CSS

It would read out the text inside the div so keep it relavent.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `aria-label`

```
<div aria-label="Say this word" />
```